# Should PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING be set to false?

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, mojarra

It seems that today (April 2012), both MyFaces and Mojarra's JSF 2.1 implementations have defects around partial state saving and that PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING should be set to false.

Is this true?

Comment: MyFaces code is ok. There are no open issues related to PSS at the moment (2012-APR). Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> *Should PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING be set to false?*

**Only** when you encounter a general defect related to partial state saving in your webapp which can *really not* be solved/workarounded the other way. Partial state saving has namely major advantages as to overall performance and memory usage. See also [Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side/5475564#5475564)

I can't 100% reliably speak for MyFaces, but in Mojarra the root cause of problems around partial state saving will manifest when you're binding any attribute of a tag handler (tag handlers are recognizeable by the lack of the `rendered` attribute on the tag such as JSTL tags) to a view scoped bean, or when you're binding the `id` or `binding` attribute of a JSF component to a view scoped bean (those attributes are namely resolved during building/restoring the view).

This problem is caused by a chicken-egg issue as described in [JSF issue 1492](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/1496) and [JSF spec issue 787](https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/787): with partial state saving enabled, the view scoped beans were stored in the partial view state. So to extract view scoped beans, the partial view state has to be restored. During restoring (building) the view, the EL in all of the aforementioned attributes will be evaluated. However, since there's no view scoped bean instance available at that moment, a brand new one instance will be created. This will however have all its properties set to default! After restoring the view and getting the original view scoped beans back, they will be put back in the view scope, overridding the (temporary) instances created during restoring the view. But the EL expressions of those attributes are already been evaluated based on a completely different instance and can't be restored.

This chicken-egg issue is solved since Mojarra 2.1.18 and 2.2.0 by storing view scoped beans in session. If you can't upgrade for some reason, then this can indeed be solved by disabling the partial state saving by setting `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` to `false`. An alternative is to just *not* bind the aforementioned attributes to a view scoped bean at all, but look for an alternative solution.

You could also set the `javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS` instead. This allows you to specify a comma separated list of all view IDs for which partial state saving needs to be turned off:

```html
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
    <param-value>/some.xhtml,/other.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This allows you to benefit from partial state saving as much as possible and turn it off for only a subset of views on which the partial state saving related problems can really not be fixed.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - `@ViewScoped` fails in tag handlers](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers)

Comment: Ahh-- did not realize that javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS existed. Glad they added that... Thanks. Best of both worlds until a proper solution is found.

Comment: what is the format for view IDs? and what should it start with?

Comment: @JoshuaH: a "view ID" is just the absolute web content path to the physical file. The example in my answer points two files: `/some.xhtml` and `/other.xhtml`.