# FaceletContext is Null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a JSF 2.0 project that I am unable to obtain a FaceletContext from.

Here is the setup from my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
    <param-value>/index.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I can obtain the FacesContext, but not the FaceletContext. The following lines of code are where the issue lies:

```
            FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); //works
    //FaceletContext f2ctx = (FaceletContext) fctx.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
    FaceletContext f2ctx = (FaceletContext) fctx.getELContext().getContext(FaceletContext.class);
```

Can anyone assist?

Update:

The above was a snippet from my overall goal: loading a facelet file containing a dialog on demand, then add it to a parent to display. The code below is incomplete, but should explain what I'm getting at. Note that the app uses the Primefaces library, hence the RequestContext object.

```
public void launch() {

    form.getChildren().clear();

    FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    for (Object o: fctx.getAttributes().keySet()) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }

    FaceletContext f2ctx = (FaceletContext) fctx.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
    //FaceletContext f2ctx = (FaceletContext) fctx.getELContext().getContext(FaceletContext.class);
    dialog = new Dialog();

    try {
        f2ctx.includeFacelet(dialog, "/WEB-INF/facelets/dialog/manager.xhtml");
        form.getChildren().add(dialog);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.debug(ex.toString());
    }

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("mainPageCenterForm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be `null` when you try to access it before the view is ever been built. For example, during the `beforePhase` of `RESTORE_VIEW` phase. Rearrange your code logic. It's not clear what's the functional requirement is and where exactly you're trying to access it, so I can't give a more suited answer.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS` context param is **ignored** when the partial state saving is disabled. Perhaps that was not your intent? See also this related answer [Should PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING be set to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337015/should-partial-state-saving-be-set-to-false/10337452#10337452)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue, it was leftover from some experimenting. I added the full method and an explanation of what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, I cannot use a dynamic ui:include to do what I need.

Comment: When exactly is `launch()` called? What do you get when you debug/print `FacesContext#getViewRoot()` and `FacesContext#getCurrentPhaseId()`?

Comment: I'm seeing your point about why it's null. The launch method is being called as an action in a Primefaces MenuItem, but that is defined on another page (index.xhtml). However, the app is dialog-heavy (customer requirement), so I'm trying to figure out how to do a load on demand for the relevant Facelet.

Comment: Try `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.someCondition}"><ui:include src="/WEB-INF/facelets/dialog/manager.xhtml"/></h:panelGroup>` straight in the view instead.

Comment: FacesContext#getViewRoot() returns a UIComponentBase, and getCurrentPhaseId() returns "INVOKE_APPLICATION"

Comment: Well, I'd expect it to return non-null then. What JSF impl/version and PrimeFaces version exactly? Or wait, is it an ajax request?

Comment: JSF is glassfish jsf 2.0 as provided by Weblogic server, and Primefaces is 3.2.

Comment: I don't have Weblogic at hands now, but all I can tell based on earlier problems/questions I've read before is that it's a rather odd beast. Have you already given the expliciet view markup with `<h:panelGroup rendered>` a try?

Comment: I haven't done that yet. Question: will the ui:include be processed regardless, but only rendered when the condition becomes true? Or will the ui:include only "trigger" once that condition is true?

Comment: It will be processed during view build time regardless. You could use `<c:if>` instead. But this may have another undesireable side effects.

Comment: Okay, that's what I'm trying to avoid, since the application is dialog heavy, but a given user may only use a few of those dialogs during a given session. I might try switching over to Mojarra 2.0 and see if there is a difference.

Comment: I just did a quick test with Mojarra 2.1.7 on Tomcat 7.0.26 and Glassfish 3.1.1 and it returns non-null to me.

Comment: You're fortunate... I had no luck. Guess I'll try tomcat next just to see if it's Oracle's usual policy of making life miserable for developers.

Comment: Nope, same error on Tomcat. Might have to figure out a different way to do this.

Comment: In Myfaces, some good hacks were done to solve the problems over ui:include / c:if . It is better to let facelets build the component tree, so if you can, it is better to use template tags or a composite component. Try to change the component tree outside facelets (on the managed bean) works too, but that causes problems later when the view is refreshed, and increase the state size without need.

Comment: Moved this to a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353381/unable-to-reference-faceletcontext-in-a-managed-bean