# Primefaces Datatable sortField null and filters map {} when created programatically

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

When lazy datatable is created programatically (using binding and valExp) sortField is always null, sortorder Ascending, filters map {}. That is on clicking a sortfield or typing a string in filter field.

When the same is done WITHOUT binding, all in xhtml view, everything works as advertised. I have also looked at PhaseListener loading sequence, and didn't find anything different in both cases, only that in first it doesnt work.

TestController is @ViewScoped. Tried with PF versions 3.5, 3.4.2, 3.3.1, 3.3.

Am I doing it wrong?

view

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{testController.datatable}" />   

  <p:dataTable value="#{testController.testModel}" var="val" rows="5" lazy="true">
     <p:column sortBy="#{val}">
        #{val}
     </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

generation

```
datatable = new DataTable();
  datatable.setValueExpression("lazy",createValueExpression("true", Boolean.class));
  datatable.setValueExpression("rows",createValueExpression("10", Integer.class));
  datatable.setValueExpression("value",createValueExpression("#{testController.testModel}", DataModel.class));
  datatable.setVar("val");


  Column column = new Column();
  column.setValueExpression("sortBy", createValueExpression("#{val}", String.class));

  HtmlOutputText output = (HtmlOutputText) application.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
  output.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{val}", String.class));

  column.getChildren().add(output);

  datatable.getChildren().add(column);
```

model

```
public List<String> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
    List<String> modelMock = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("abc");
            add("def");
        }
    };
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("load()");
    }

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("first " + first + " pageSize" + pageSize);

        LOGGER.debug("sortField -> " + sortField);
        LOGGER.debug("sortOrder -> " + sortOrder);
        LOGGER.debug("filters -> " + filters);
    }

    this.setRowCount(modelMock.size());

    return modelMock;
}
```

debug output

```
11:12:24,426 DEBUG TestModel:33 - load()
11:12:24,426 DEBUG TestModel:37 - first 0 pageSize10
11:12:24,426 DEBUG TestModel:39 - sortField -> null
11:12:24,426 DEBUG TestModel:40 - sortOrder -> ASCENDING
11:12:24,426 DEBUG TestModel:41 - filters -> {}
```

The second datatable is proof that when the same is not used with binding, that it works

```
11:21:25,677 DEBUG TestModel:33 - load()
11:21:25,677 DEBUG TestModel:37 - first 0 pageSize5
11:21:25,677 DEBUG TestModel:39 - sortField -> val
11:21:25,677 DEBUG TestModel:40 - sortOrder -> DESCENDING
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem between '**binding**' elements and '**@ViewScoped**' scope.
You can read more information here : http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html#HeyTheresPitfallsInTheTitle

One solution, if you want to keep your binding and your current scope is to enable full state saving for components. You can setting it up for a specified page by adding this to your **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <!-- For Bug Fixing Viewscope beans with binding component attributes -->
    <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
    <param-value>/faces/myPageWithBindings.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: What is the drawback of using javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS ? Overhead?

Comment: It can affect performances by increasing memory usage for example. You can read information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337015/should-partial-state-saving-be-set-to-false