# Error in WebSphere 8.5 + Mojarra + MyFaces2 + Spring webflow

Tags: primefaces, websphere, myfaces, mojarra, websphere-8

I am trying to deploy a web application in WebSphere 8.5. The app has the following characteristics.

- Mojarra 2.1.13
- Primefaces 3.4.2
- spring webflow 2.3.1
- spring 3.1.2
- jdk 1.6

This app works very well into Tomcat 7 but when we try to deploy it into WebSphere we got a `NullPointerException` with the following stacktrace.

```
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreDeltaSystemEventListenerClassMap(UIComponentBase.java:1933)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1765)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.restoreState(UIViewRoot.java:1214)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1401)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processRestoreState(UIViewRoot.java:731)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewStateManager.restoreComponentState(FlowViewStateManager.java:78)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewStateManager.restoreView(FlowViewStateManager.java:203)
org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageBase.restoreView(ViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:106)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.restoreView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1438)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:278)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreFlowView(FlowViewHandler.java:144)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreView(FlowViewHandler.java:83)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfViewFactory.getView(JsfViewFactory.java:105)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:193)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
com.csc.fsg.pcdSecurity.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:573)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
```

I see that the error is coming from MyFaces2, JSF implementation by default into websphere 8.5, so I tried to implement Mojarra 2.1.13 as a shared lib but it did not work (I followed the steps from IBM docs).

The other odd thing is that the app rendered the main page but when it is rendering suddenly this error shows up.

- Does someone know something about this error?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337015/should-partial-state-saving-be-set-to-false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piero,

To resolve the problem, add or replace the following context parameter in the web.xml file and republish the project.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

That is because you are using a default JSF implementation for WAS (myFaces) and you have developed in mojarra, so you need to set that in order to work with myFaces.

Saludos

Comment: Turn off javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING could be a very bad idea? This could significantly degrade your app performance. Our app was developed with Mojarra, and we support WAS 8.5 as well, and it will work together, but lots of effort were put to it to make it work though.

Comment: Thang, Could you please share what kind of efforts you had to make in order to works ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have:

1. JSF Mojarra 2.1.7
2. Primefaces 3.4.2
3. Spring framework 4.0.2.RELEASE
4. Spring web flow 2.3.3.RELEASE
5. Spring security 3.2.0.RELEASE

I resolved in this mode:

1. Change class loader of the module  in PARENT_LAST

   [ibm documentation (change class loader policy)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/crun_classload.html)
2. Change JSF Provider

   [ibm documentation (change jsf provider)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/tweb_jsf.html)
3. Restart Server **(Important!)**