# NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createView

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, websphere-8

i am trying to upgrade from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2.2.2 on websphere 8.5.1
and what i did is as follows:

1- put **jsf-api-2.2.2.jar** and **jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar** in my lib folder.

2- changed header of web.xml to be as follows:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="YourWebappID"
    version="2.5">
```

3- changed header of **faces-config.xml** to be as follows:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

4- changed the faces servlet to be as follows:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

5- changed the classloader to be parent last on websphere, and i can see in the logs that mojara was initialized successfully.

6- my xhtml page is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World</h3>
        <h:form>
           <h:inputText id="sname" value="test" />   
        </h:form>             
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and i am getting the following exception:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.sun.rave.web.ui.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter.doFilter(SecurityPluginFilter.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3748)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:812)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.createView(MultiViewHandler.java:166)
    at com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.createView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:254)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    ... 36 more

[2/26/14 12:50:50:839 AST] 0000009a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\CPAppSrv\logs\ffdc\server1_71182b64_14.02.26_12.50.50.8215897287481496037428.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter 82
[2/26/14 12:50:50:856 AST] 0000009a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\CPAppSrv\logs\ffdc\server1_71182b64_14.02.26_12.50.50.8391240912466991529797.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter 144
[2/26/14 12:50:50:856 AST] 0000009a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\CPAppSrv\logs\ffdc\server1_71182b64_14.02.26_12.50.50.8561570983167716244235.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -SE 1078
[2/26/14 12:50:50:856 AST] 0000009a webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:812)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.createView(MultiViewHandler.java:166)
    at com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.createView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:254)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.sun.rave.web.ui.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter.doFilter(SecurityPluginFilter.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3748)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
```

please advise about this error, do i have to add javaee jars to my lib folder ? do i have to add jsf listener in web.xml ?

EDIT:

This was solved by removing the jsf-api-2.2.2.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar

and using javax.faces-2.0.10.jar and jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar,but i want to make it work with

jsf-api-2.2.2.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar, please advise how to solve above exception with latest mojara jars.

Comment: What did you see in FFDC log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing the **jsf-api-2.2.2.jar** and **jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar**

and using **javax.faces-2.0.10.jar** and **jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar**

Comment: i solved by removing jsf2.2 jar and adding jsf1.2 jar

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.2 requires at least Servlet 3.0. Reading the definition of your web.xml i see you're still using Servlet 2.5. Change your first line with

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```

And your faces-config definition should be like

```
<faces-config version="2.2"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server 8.5 using MyFaces JSF Implementation by default.
There is article in [IBM Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html) how to use different JSF implementations.

Comment: I've found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490391/error-in-websphere-8-5-mojarra-myfaces2-spring-webflow/22145399#22145399

Answer (score -1):

Also faced with same error during migration Struts 1 -> JSF 2.2
It was occurred by ViewHandlerImpl of struts-faces (1.3.8).
Looks like this lib is incompatible with Servlet 3 (which is required by JSF 2.2)

PS: Was working with JSF 2.0 without any changes.

So I can suggest to check all 3rd part filters etc., which can be involved to request processing.

Note for Author, please, pay attention to your code in:

```
com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter
...
com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter
```

Comment: This actually answers a different question. Try finding the right question or just ask your own.

Comment: Sorry, maybe yes but actually I had the same Exception and almost the same stack trace - so similar issue.
And I found where was problem on my side and gave some shot suggestion as one of the variants to what direction to dig.
Because solution to downgrade JSF to 2.0 is surface.