# JSF 2.2 components are not rendered using Primefaces running on Spring and Maven

Tags: jsf-2.2

When I go to http://localhost:8081/installer/index.xhtml via IE11 or Firefox45, I see only Setup Wizard and no JSF components. The HTTP status code is 200. I do not have any errors on Tomcat 7.
It is running without problem on JSF 1.2. I am only not sure about web.xml file.

Thanks in advance. Can you advise me what can be wrong, please?

**EDITED**
When I changed extension from .xhtml to .faces, I got an useful exception on Tomcat output, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the servlet mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now which url you are running like here servlet is called when i will run `http://localhost:Port/Path/PageName.jsf` but when i will try to run `http://localhost:Port/Path/PageName.xhtml` it will not work. Or I have to us like this `http://localhost:Port/faces/Path/PageName.xhtml`

- [What is the difference between creating .xhtml or .jsp .or .jsf for JSF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-jsf-pages-with-jsp-or-xhtml-or-jsf-ex)
- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)

Comment: I am running http://localhost:8081/installer/index.xhtml

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>30</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: What about your servlet mapping in web.xml file ?

Comment: try this url  http://localhost:8081/installer/index.faces

Comment: I ran localhost:8081/installer/index.faces and I got 

#{msg.WEB_ERROR_SHOW_TRACE} #{msg.WEB_ERROR_LINK_BACK} #{msg.WEB_ERROR_LINK_HOME} #{msg.WEB_TOOLBAR_BTN_SETTINGS} #{msg.WEB_TOOLBAR_BTN_LOGIN}

Comment: Try with simple code first just add one two component in page and render it see what is happening.

Comment: I ran http://localhost:8081/installer/index.faces. Looks the same no component only text.
Here is my JS console.
GET 
http://localhost:8081/installer/index.faces [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 194ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8081/allfa-web/pages/login.faces [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 22ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8081/installer/index.faces [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 4ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8081/allfa-web/pages/login.faces [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 5ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8081/allfa-web/pages/index.faces [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 5ms]

and so on...

Comment: My simple page with a component.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>
        <p:editor value="#{editor.value}" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>

Comment: Your Simple Page worked or not?

Comment: My simple page not worked. I got
#{msg.WEB_ERROR_SHOW_TRACE} #{msg.WEB_ERROR_LINK_BACK} #{msg.WEB_ERROR_LINK_HOME} #{msg.WEB_TOOLBAR_BTN_SETTINGS} #{msg.WEB_TOOLBAR_BTN_LOGIN}

Comment: If you migrating from JSF1.2 to JSF2 did you follow standard document .How you are migrating ?

Comment: I have changed pom.xml, web.xml, faces-config.xml to meet Java EE 7 standarrd requirements. However, I am migrating also from icefaces to primfaces 5.2. So, I commented out many lines related to icefaces on back-end and a few on front-end.

Comment: This is my tomcat output when I run http://localhost:8081/installer/example.faces

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:822)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.createView(MultiViewHandler.java:168)
 at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.createView(PrettyViewHandler.java:55)

Comment: @Michal Please have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038140/nullpointerexception-at-com-sun-faces-application-view-faceletviewhandlingstrate