# @EJB in @ViewScoped @ManagedBean causes java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: serialization, jsf-2, ejb, myfaces, managed-bean

I've read [@EJB in @ViewScoped managed bean causes java.io.NotSerializableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037722/ejb-in-viewscoped-managed-bean-causes-java-io-notserializableexception), but my state saving setting is `server`.

Here is what I have:

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>sispra</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>glass-x</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>fileRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

`customer.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">      

    <h:head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <p:growl id="messages"/>

        <h:form>

            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{customerController.create}" value="save" update="@form :messages"/>

            <p:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Details"/>
                </f:facet>

                <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{bundle['person.name']}"/>
                    <p:inputText id="name" label="#{bundle['person.name']}" value="#{customerController.selected.name}"/>
                    <p:message for="name"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="#{bundle['person.surname']}"/>
                    <p:inputText id="surname" label="#{bundle['person.surname']}" value="#{customerController.selected.surname}"/>
                    <p:message for="surname"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

`CustomerController.java`:

```
package it.shape.sispra.controllers;

import it.shape.sispra.ejb.PersonFacade;
import it.shape.sispra.entities.Customer;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CustomerController extends AbstractController<Customer>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 134755304347034L;

    @EJB
    private PersonFacade facade;

    public CustomerController()
    {
        super(Customer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonFacade getFacade()
    {
        return facade;
    }
}
```

`PersonFacade.java`:

```
package it.shape.sispra.ejb;

import it.shape.sispra.entities.Person;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class PersonFacade extends AbstractFacade<Person>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4357823648345L;

    public PersonFacade()
    {
        super(Person.class);
    }

}
```

AbstractFacade.java:

```
package it.shape.sispra.ejb;

import it.shape.sispra.entities.AbstractEntity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaHelper;
import org.eclipse.persistence.queries.QueryByExamplePolicy;
import org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery;
import org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T extends AbstractEntity> implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12467890452346123L;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sispra")
    private EntityManager em;

    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass)
    {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        return em;
    }

    public void create(T entity)
    {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity)
    {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity)
    {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public void refresh(T entity)
    {
        getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
    }

    public T find(Object id)
    {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll()
    {
        CriteriaQuery<T> cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(entityClass);
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));

        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int first, int max)
    {
        CriteriaQuery<T> cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(entityClass);
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));

        TypedQuery<T> q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(max);
        q.setFirstResult(first);

        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count()
    {
        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        TypedQuery<Long> q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return q.getSingleResult().intValue();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T findByExample(T entity)
    {
        // Create a native EclipseLink query using QBE policy
        QueryByExamplePolicy policy = new QueryByExamplePolicy();
        policy.addSpecialOperation(String.class, "like");

        ReadObjectQuery roq = new ReadObjectQuery(entity, policy);

        // Wrap the native query in a standard JPA Query and execute it
        Query query = JpaHelper.createQuery(roq, getEntityManager());

        return (T) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAllByExample(T entity)
    {
        // Create a native EclipseLink query using QBE policy
        QueryByExamplePolicy policy = new QueryByExamplePolicy();
        policy.addSpecialOperation(String.class, "like");

        ReadAllQuery raq = new ReadAllQuery(entity, policy);

        // Wrap the native query in a standard JPA Query and execute it
        Query query = JpaHelper.createQuery(raq, getEntityManager());

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findByExample(T entity, int start, int max)
    {
        // Create a native EclipseLink query using QBE policy
        QueryByExamplePolicy policy = new QueryByExamplePolicy();
        policy.addSpecialOperation(String.class, "like");

        ReadAllQuery raq = new ReadAllQuery(entity, policy);

        // Wrap the native query in a standard JPA Query and execute it
        Query query = JpaHelper.createQuery(raq, getEntityManager());
        query.setFirstResult(start);
        query.setMaxResults(max);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public int countByExample(T entity)
    {
        //TODO find a better way...
        return findAllByExample(entity).size();
    }
}
```

and this is the stacktrace:

```
GRAVE: Exiting serializeView - Could not serialize state: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
  at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
  at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.serializeView(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:357)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.saveSerializedViewInServletSession(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:220)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.saveSerializedView(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:798)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.saveState(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:127)
  at org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
  at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1554)
  at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281)
  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
  at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
  at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
  at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
  at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I know I can workaround this by declaring `PersonFacade` as `transient` and use JNDI to get EJB reference after recontruction, but I really dislike this approach.

Is it possible that Glassfish 3.1.1 provides non-serializable EJBs? Is there a way to use `@EJB` and `@ViewScoped` together?

**update:**
i found that this is a MyFaces related issue, all is working fine using mojarra

Comment: I gather that `AbstractFacade<T> implements Serializable`?

Comment: yes,  just edit post with `AbstractFacade` code too :)

Comment: however, setting `@SessionScoped` will work. how can this happen? if i am right, `@SessionScoped` beans follow same serialization of `@ViewScoped`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:)  I had the same problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3581

David Blevins over at the Apache TomEE helped me a log a bug and patch for MyFaces. The problem was generated proxy classes aren't on the classloader path for their deserializer.

A workaround is to set this web-app param to false: `org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION`

Answer (score 7):

I have seen the problem too.  What I have done in the past is split my bean into a `StateBean` which is `@ViewScoped` and an `ActionsBean` which is `@RequestScoped`.  The `ActionBean` is injected with the `StateBean` as well as any EJBs or non-serializable resource accessing objects.  On the front-end you use the `StateBean` for accessing properties and `ActionsBean` for performing actions.

I would love to hear from someone else who would make my "bean splitting" pattern deprecated.

This is an example of what I do:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CustomControllerStateBean implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 134755304347034L;

  private Person selected;

  public Person getSelected() {
    return selected;
  }

  public void setSelected(Person selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
  }
}
```

*Notice `CustomControllerStateBean` is `@ViewScoped` and is `Serializable` an only contains `Serializable` objects.*

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CustomControllerActionsBean {

  @EJB
  private PersonFacade facade;
  @Inject
  private CustomControllerStateBean state;

  public void create() {
    facade.create(state.getSelected());
  }
}
```

*Notice `CustomControllerActionsBean` is `@RequestScoped` and is NOT `Serializable` an contains non-`Serializable` objects.*

Your front-end will no look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">      

    <h:head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <p:growl id="messages"/>

        <h:form>

            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{customerControllerActionsBean.create}" value="save" update="@form :messages"/>

            <p:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Details"/>
                </f:facet>

                <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{bundle['person.name']}"/>
                    <p:inputText id="name" label="#{bundle['person.name']}" value="#{customerControllerStateBean.selected.name}"/>
                    <p:message for="name"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="#{bundle['person.surname']}"/>
                    <p:inputText id="surname" label="#{bundle['person.surname']}" value="#{customerControllerStateBean.selected.surname}"/>
                    <p:message for="surname"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

*Notice `CustomControllerActionsBean` is used at the top in the `p:commandButton` and `CustomControllerStateBean` is used in the `p:inputText`s.*

Comment: drawback is that you need to split every ViewScoped controller and it requires a lot of refactoring effort. however this is a nicer workaround than EJB lookup, so deserves a +1 :) thx

Comment: You do have to split everything.  In my experience it isn't always bad.  Having state and actions separate helps keep things clean.  I don't have huge beans anymore.  However, sometimes splitting small beans makes it less readable.  In those instances, it is very annoying.

Comment: Nice workaround... although I don't understand why the OP doesn't work.

Comment: @exabrial The problem is `@ViewScoped` beans are stored in the session and anything stored in the session is supposed to be `Serializable`.  `CustomerController` isn't `Serializable`, so it can't be `ViewScoped`.  I split my code so that everything that isn't `Serializable` is  `RequestScoped`, so that they don't need to be `Serializable`.

Comment: My EJBs are serializable, so they can be passivated on demand. Take a look at this too: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3581

Comment: @pgreen2 CustomerController **is** Serializable, just as contained EJB. my problem was about this: how is it possible that a Serializable Object cannot be serialized?

Comment: @exabrial put this link in a new answer and i'll accept it :)

Comment: @animanera To be truly Serializable, it requires more than just adding the interface Serializable to a class.  By default, Java will try to serialize a class by serializing all fields that aren't transient.  So all fields of a class also will need to be serializable.  If they aren't you can see serializable exceptions similar to what you are seeing.  You can override the default mechanism to how your class is serialized by overriding writeObject(), readObject(), and/or readObjectNoData().  I could be mistaken, but I don't think EntityManager is serializable.  Could you move it to an EJB?

Comment: @pgreen2 **each** object contained in my EJB **should** be serializable, but you are right `EntityManager` (and in my case `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl` and every parent interface) does **NOT** implement `Serializable`. this is very strange. maybe EJB generated proxy have a `transient` reference to injected `EntityManager`. i can't move it to EJB since i changed my business model and now i'm using mojarra without problem. but i'm sure that mojarra let me inject it in a parent class while myfaces don't. how can this be possible if the EJB container is the same??

Comment: @animanera you are verging on the edge of my knowledge.  The invisible magic that could be affecting things is proxies.  With a lot of these frameworks that handle scoping, they proxy most all of the classes.  They normally create a singleton proxy that is injected and the proxy determines the correct delegate based upon the scope.  The proxy can be smart enough to handle serialization.  This is where my experience ends.  I have never checked the proxying code, so the times I thought the proxy was doing it, it could have been something else.  However, I don't see why a proxy couldn't do it.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti: The EJB container might be the same, but then there is a concept of shallow & deep copy.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti: On the server side, the state can be stored as a shallow or a deep copy. In a shallow copy, state is not serialized in the session (JSF stores only pointers to the state in a session and only the container deals with serialization stuff), which requires less memory and allows you to inject EJBs in the view scoped beans (use this technique carefully, since the changes that affect objects in one copy will be reflected in the rest of the copies). The deep copy represents a full serialization of the state in a session, which requires more memory and doesn't allow injecting EJBs.