# How to find missing class when you get "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: void"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, ehcache, shiro

I am using Shiro in a JSF 2 (maven) project running on Glassfish. All related dependencies (shiro-ehcache-1.2.2.jar, ehcache-core-2.5.0) are added. My project compiles and runs smoothly but as soon as I mark a ManagedBean with @ViewScoped annotation, I get this irritating ClassNotFound Exception:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: void
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509) 
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:129) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.PreferTCCLObjectInputStream.resolveClass(PreferTCCLObjectInputStream.java:44) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1461) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1311) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) 
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) 
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) 
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) 
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.SimpleSession.readObject(SimpleSession.java:500) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.Element.readObject(Element.java:800) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.read(DiskStorageFactory.java:378) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.retrieve(DiskStorageFactory.java:960) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.decodeHit(Segment.java:178) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.get(Segment.java:216) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.get(DiskStore.java:504) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.getQuiet(DiskStore.java:511) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.getQuiet(FrontEndCacheTier.java:196) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.searchInStoreWithoutStats(Cache.java:2101) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1630) 
    at org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache.get(EhCache.java:73) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.CachingSessionDAO.getCachedSession(CachingSessionDAO.java:217) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.CachingSessionDAO.getCachedSession(CachingSessionDAO.java:202) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.CachingSessionDAO.readSession(CachingSessionDAO.java:259) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSessionManager.java:236) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSession(DefaultSessionManager.java:222) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.doGetSession(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:118) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:108) 
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.getSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:100) 
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.SessionsSecurityManager.getSession(SessionsSecurityManager.java:125) 
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveContextSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:456) 
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:442) 
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.createSubject(DefaultSecurityManager.java:338) 
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:846) 
    at org.apache.shiro.web.subject.WebSubject$Builder.buildWebSubject(WebSubject.java:148) 
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.createSubject(AbstractShiroFilter.java:292) 
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359) 
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231) 
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317) 
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

As the exception happens internally in shiro-ehcache classes and it says: **"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: void"** I cannot infer, which class or jar is causing the trouble. It seems one of my beans cannot be serialized but which one? My question is:

How can we find offending classes in such a situation?

Edit: I have a navigation bean which is sessionscoped:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NavigationBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

@Inject
private transient Logger log;

private String page = "/subpages/admin_home.xhtml";

public NavigationBean() {
}

public String getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;

}


}
```

And another sessionscoped bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SettingsBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private transient Logger log;

private static final Locale Turkish = new Locale("tr");
private static final Locale English = Locale.ENGLISH;
private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
private static final Map<String,Object> countries;
static {
        countries = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
        countries.put("English", English); //label, value
        countries.put("Türkçe", Turkish);
}

/**
 * Creates a new instance of SettingsBean
 */
public SettingsBean() {
    System.out.print("Settings bean constructed");
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    log.debug ("Settings bean initialized");
}

public Locale getLocale() {
    return locale;
} 

public String getLanguage() {
    String lang = locale.getLanguage();
    if (lang.equals("en_US")){lang="en";}
    else if (lang.equals("tr_tr")){lang="tr";}
    return lang;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    locale = new Locale(language);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);

    //String Msg = Messages.getResourceBundleString("M","LanguageChanged");
    String Msg = Messages.getString("LanguageChanged");

    FacesMessage facesmsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, Msg, "");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesmsg);
    log.debug(Msg + " : " + language);
}

public Map<String, Object> getCountriesInMap() {
        return countries;
}


//value change event listener
public void countryLocaleCodeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e){

    String newLocaleValue = e.getNewValue().toString();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : countries.entrySet()) {

       if(entry.getValue().toString().equals(newLocaleValue)){
                            setLanguage(entry.getValue().toString());
      }
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide any code where this error raises or probably a Facelets code related with the error.

Comment: It looks like your view scoped bean is not serialized correctly. Have a look at it, maybe some fields (like injected services) should be marked as transient?

Comment: I have updated the question to add "probably related" facelets code..

Comment: I think problem is related to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761622/ejb-in-viewscoped-managedbean-causes-java-io-notserializableexception It is about different classloaders.. I cannot find a way...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jboss's [tattle tale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale/downloads) to introspect a project's lib folder and graphically map out the dependency tree. Using this tool, you can find out a class' dependencies. After downloading and unpacking the project, run thru the following steps to find out which class is breaking:

1. From your command line, run the the tattletale jar. For example

   ```
   java -jar -Xmx512m tattletale.jar   <the path with your libraries> <the destination folder where you want the generated reports to be stored>
   ```
2. In the output folder, you'll find a tree of folders and an *index.html* file. Open this file and select the *depends on* link.
3. In the **depends on** page, you'll find all the classes in your libraries and a list of all the dependencies of each. A simple "find" operation will tell you which class is missing the class you've highlighted

Comment: I was not aware of "tattle tale" before. So it is good to know.. Thanks @kolossus...

Answer (score 0):

As @mrembisz pointed out I have checked my viewscoped beans. I was injecting a stateles bean into my viewscoped bean and although it was implementing "Serializable", probably one or more of its properties were not serializible. So I changed

```
@Inject
MyBean MB;
```

to

```
@Inject
private transient MyBean MB;
```

And I tought the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: void" went away.. But as I do not get that exception at first, it is still being thrown occasionally. I now get:

```
INFO: 2013-07-18 15:21:06,123 ERROR o.a.s.w.s.AbstractShiroFilter - session.touch() method invocation has failed.  Unable to updatethe corresponding session's last access time based on the incoming request.org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: void

at org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache.put(EhCache.java:105) ~[shiro-ehcache-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.CachingSessionDAO.cache(CachingSessionDAO.java:247) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.CachingSessionDAO.cache(CachingSessionDAO.java:235) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.CachingSessionDAO.update(CachingSessionDAO.java:280) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.onChange(DefaultSessionManager.java:212) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.touch(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:193) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DelegatingSession.touch(DelegatingSession.java:120) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.touch(ProxiedSession.java:100) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.updateSessionLastAccessTime(AbstractShiroFilter.java:315) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:364) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.50]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_38]

Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: void
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.retrieve(DiskStorageFactory.java:890) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.decode(Segment.java:172) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.put(Segment.java:449) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.put(DiskStore.java:438) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.put(FrontEndCacheTier.java:267) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1455) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1383) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1348) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache.put(EhCache.java:102) ~[shiro-ehcache-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
... 39 common frames omitted


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: void
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509) ~[war-util.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359) ~[war-util.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:129) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.util.PreferTCCLObjectInputStream.resolveClass(PreferTCCLObjectInputStream.java:44) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1461) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1311) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.SimpleSession.readObject(SimpleSession.java:500) ~[shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at net.sf.ehcache.Element.readObject(Element.java:844) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.read(DiskStorageFactory.java:370) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.retrieve(DiskStorageFactory.java:886) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar:na]
... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This is not the right approach. Injected CDI/EJB instances are per definition serializable proxies which in turn delegate to the "current instance" in the desired scope (via `ThreadLocal` mechanisms similar to `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()`). If you declare them `transient`, then the proxy instances are not serialized in the state and reappear as `null` after deserialization. If any JSF form action methods rely on them thereafter, then they'll throw NPEs in all colors. So, if you only use them during `@PostConstruct`, then this is harmless, but still, this is absolutely not the right way.

Comment: @BalusC you nailed it! I now see why I should not mark CDI/EJB instances transient. Then what is the "right" way? I have to use ViewScoped or SessionScoped state beans and I want to have EJB's providing services to them. What is the legitimitate way?