# ViewScope in managed bean throwing NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Right now I'm facing the following issue:

I'm using @ViewScoped in my Managed bean, but when the application is redering the JSF is throwing the following exception:

```
Grave: Error Rendering View[/historico/reporteHistoricoComparativo.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1133)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1133)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
```

Yes,i did read all the questions posted here, but no clear answer is given. Yes,I did put implemens Serialiable in all my Managed beans that are invoked in my JSF page.

The exception remarks an EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegatel, so it seems the problem is with an @EJB attribute in the managed bean. In the interfaces I put "extends Serializable" and on the implementation classes I wrote "implements Serializable".

Is there any way to know which class is causing the exception?

I'm not using Spring!

I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: I marked every managed bean in my application as "implements Serializable" however,the exception persists. Also, the EJB's within the managed beans were marked as stateful, but..... still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your web.xml to see if you have client side saving is on and it's the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037722/ejb-in-viewscoped-managed-bean-causes-java-io-notserializableexception).

The container should have deserialized the managed bean and inject the EJB without giving this exception, also it should not have serialized an EJB property.