# what is "Java beans"?

Tags: java, javabeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [places where Java Beans used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-java-beans-used)

Can anyone tell me what exactly "Java beans" is and why is it used?

Comment: And the first link off Google was too hard? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

Comment: @tim_yates: That's not a useful comment, nor is it appreciated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: What, posting a link to a good article explaining the answer?  I humbly apologise, and hope you will forgive me for my helpful intrusion...

Comment: @tim_yates: My honest apologies...I thought that was a Google-link. oO'

Answer (score 3):

#### Links

- [Wikipedia/JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean)
- [java.sun.com - Developer - Online Training - Introducing Java Beans](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Beans/Beans1/)

Answer (score -1):

I do not like the term java bean, it just causes confusion because every properly written java class is per definition a java bean, that is, using proper encapsulation rules and so on.

But take care, sometimes people who are saying java bean, mean enterprise java bean (EJB) which is are classes which derive from special classes in the java EE framework.