# java beans in java

Tags: java, javabeans

how components interact with each other in java beans

Comment: possible duplicate of [places where Java Beans used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-java-beans-used)

Comment: Do you realize that almost every question of yours get closed? I suggest to get yourself through this article to learn how to ask good questions: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

You must understand, what Java Beans are, in the first place. So here is the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Beans). As it turns out, after reading from the link provided, its nothing special but a normal Java classes follow some conventions.

BTW, for Enterprise Java Beans, read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Java_Beans) (a wiki link, again). Its to avoid any confusion between the two.