# How to implement a dynamic nav without repeating html in multiple JSP/JSTL files

Tags: java, jsp, redundancy

I have this nav code in multiple JSP files:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li ><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active" ><a href="/bills">Bills</a></li>
    <li ><a href="/invoices">Invoices</a></li>
</ul>
```

What's the best way to abstract out this code and make the selection of the `active` nav element programmatic rather than manually defined in the html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<jsp:include>` to include reuseable JSP code fragments.

```xml
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/nav.jsp" />
```

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)/[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to dynamically control HTML output.

```xml
<ul id="nav">
    <c:forEach items="${pages}" var="page">
        <c:set var="active" value="${fn:endsWith(pageContext.request.requestURI, page.url)}" />
        <li class="${active ? 'active' : 'none'}"><a href="${page.url}">${page.name}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Use a [Javabean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-java-beans-used) class to represent a model which can be used throughout all code layers.

```
public class Page {

    private String url;
    private String name;

    // Add/generate getters, setters and other boilerplate.
}
```

Use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to preload applicationwide data.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<Page>();
        pages.add(new Page("/home", "Home"));
        pages.add(new Page("/bills", "Bills"));
        // ...
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("pages", pages);
    }

    // ...
}
```