# problem with request dispatcher from servlets to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I recently started studying JSP and Servlets. I am facing problems forwarding the dataList (rows from database) to JSP using requestdispatcher. In fact I have error in my JSP page which I couldn't figure out. Since I am learning I couldnt find where the error is:

Thank you!

The following is the error I get

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /dataPage.jsp at line 29

26:         %>
27:         <tr>
28:             <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
29:             <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
30:             <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
31:             <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
32:         </tr>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:428)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    AuthenticationServlet.doPost(AuthenticationServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

my code in JSP is:

```
<table border="1" width="400">
        <tr>
            <td width="100"><b>Name</b>
            </td>
            <td width="100"><b>Contact No</b>
            </td>
            <td width="100"><b>SSN</b>
            </td>
            <td width="100"><b>Date of Birth</b>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <%  
            List<String> data = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("data");         
            Iterator<String> itr = data.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td width="100"><%=itr.next()%></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
```

My code in servlets is

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            conn.createStatement();

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name,password FROM employeeinfo WHERE name=? AND password=?");         
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, password);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs != null) {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    int i = rs.getRow();
                    if(i == 1) {
                        dataList.add(rs.getString("name"));
                        dataList.add(rs.getString("contactno"));
                        dataList.add(rs.getString("ssn"));
                        dataList.add(rs.getString("dob"));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                out.println("Invalid User !!");
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        request.setAttribute("data", dataList);
        // Dispatch the request
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
        if(dispatcher != null) {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: It's fine that you're learning JSP/Servlets. The separation of controller and view in your example is very good. However, the model is very poor (it should have been a collection of Javabeans) and you're using *scriptlets* in JSP instead of taglibs/EL. I'd suggest to learn that as the next step. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-javabeans-are-used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not selecting `contactno`, `dob` and `ssn` in your query.

Modify your query to say `select name, contactno, dob, ssn from employeeinfo WHERE ...`.

Comment: that was easy.. thank you ! I forgot about my query completely.

Comment: Yes, it was showing you have to wait 2 minutes to accept the answer.. so was just waiting !

Answer (score 0):

As @Kal correctly said that you forgot to add the data to the list, hence when you try to use `itr.next()`, it finds nothing and hence the Exception.

The Better approach will be to check the value of `itr.hasNext()` before using `itr.next()`. You may also prefer using a temporary variable to store the value returned by `itr.next()` if you want to use the same value over and over again.