# how to display data in JSTL for list containing objetcs?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

In request attribute I have list of objects (say user objects) so how can I loop through it display data on my jsp page? Can I use `<c:foreach>` but then how I can say that it is User object and access properties of that?

Comment: It's dynamic. What did you try, some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSTL/EL doesn't care about the exact type. All you need to ensure is that the object in question has a getter method for the given property so that you can just specify the property name.

Imagine,

```
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    // Getters/setters.
}
```

then you can loop over a `List<User>` like follows:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>${user.id}</td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
            <td>${user.age}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

That's it.

#### See also:

- [EL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Places where JavaBeans are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-javabeans-are-used)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue calling the object properties with JSTL when injecting with a tag. Adding `type="java.lang.Iterable"` to the incoming attribute solved the issue.

```
<%@ attribute name="myList" required="false" type="java.lang.Iterable"%>
```

So when I called it:

```
<myTags:tag 
    myList="${Class.list}">
</myTags:tag >
```