# how to display data in List Or grid or in table in Jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

This is my JSP code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.SnowballAnalyzer"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.search.Hits"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.queryParser.MultiFieldQueryParser"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException"%>

<%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.search.Query"%>

<%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.util.Version"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.document.Document"%> <%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc"%>

<%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.IOException"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.io., java.net."%>

<% //out.print("Today is:"+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

String fil = "E:\\cbdtindex";
Analyzer analyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer("English");

IndexSearcher indexSearcher;

String[] fields = { "DocType1" };

try {
    // Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(findexfile);

    IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(
            FSDirectory.open(new File(fil)), true);

    indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
            fields, analyzer);

    Query query = parser.parse("dtl");

    ScoreDoc[] hits = indexSearcher.search(query, null, 100000).scoreDocs;
    int x = hits.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        Document hitDoc = indexSearcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
        String p = hitDoc.get("FilePath");
        //System.out.println(p);
        out.println(p);

    }

    System.out.println("Length" + x);

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

I want to display String P Value in List Gird or Table.

Can someone help me? I am able to print display data in `out.print.ln` on console, but I need to display in List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jstl `<c:forEach>` for iteration and html `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` for text formatting. And it's better to use jsp as a view only without scriptlets.

Comment: where i will Use Please help me  i am new in jsp page i did work on core Java only

Comment: You can find similar question and example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120068/how-to-display-data-in-jstl-for-list-containing-objetcs

Comment: I have only one page in that am Getting data how i will create Property an all please implemnt it