# What causing java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name on my Update statement?

Tags: android, sql

This is my android SQL statement

I try to update the allergy table, I encounter a lot of problem

```
     stmt1.executeUpdate("UPDATE [dbo].[allergy] 
SET  [allergy]= "+allergyname+ ",[reaction] = "+reaction+ ",[notes] =" +notes+ " Where patientID ="+patientId);
```

no matter what I enter into my "allergyname"

It will say Invalid column name

what is happening?

Comment: SQL basics, literals should be in apostrophes ... also it is always better to use parameters

Comment: sorry can you give some example? my allergyname is a string variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLException: Invalid Column Name...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392296/sqlexception-invalid-column-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values should be in single quotes. Try below query it will work:

```
stmt1.executeUpdate("UPDATE [dbo].[allergy] 
SET  [allergy]= '"+allergyname+ "',[reaction] = '"+reaction+ "',[notes] ='" +notes+ "' Where patientID ="+patientId);
```

Happy coding!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: but still it is a bad approach ...  fx `allergyname = "I'm noob"`