# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a Bean that holds  the results. I need to use JSTL to iterate over it and present the results. Here is the bean:

```
public class DetResults
{
    private List<String> headings;
    private List<Class<?>> types;
    private List<Object[]> data;

    public DetResults() {}

    public List<String> getHeadings() { return this.headings; }
    public String getHeading(int which) { return this.headings.get(which); }

    public List<Class<?>> getTypes() { return this.types; }
    public Class<?> getType(int which) { return this.types.get(which); }

    public List<Object[]> getData( ) { return this.data; }
    public Object[] getDataAtRow( int row ) { return this.data.get(row); }


    public void setHeadings( List<String> val ) { this.headings = val; }
    public void setHeadings( String[] val ) { this.headings = Arrays.asList(val); }
    public void addHeading( String val ) 
    { 
        if( this.headings == null ) this.headings = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.headings.add(val); 
    }

    public void setTypes( List<Class<?>> val ) { this.types = val; }
    public void setTypes( Class<?> val[] ) { this.types = Arrays.asList(val); }
    public void addType( Class<?> val ) 
    {
        if( this.types == null ) this.types = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        this.types.add(val); 
    }


    public void setData( List<Object[]> val ) { this.data = val; }

    // allow NPE to get thrown
    public void setDataAtRow( Object[] val, int row ) { this.data.set(row, val); }

    public void appendDataRow( Object[] val ) 
    {
        if( data == null ) data = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); 
        this.data.add(val); 
    }

    public int getColumnCount() { return this.headings!=null?this.headings.size():0; }

}
```

Here is the handler that will set the bean to the JSP:

```
DetResults results = detDAO.fetchDetResults(paramBean);
request.setAttribute("results", results);
action.setJspURI(".../.jsp");
```

I tried to display it as follows:

```
<c:forEach var="results" items="${results}">
    ${results.heading}
</c:forEach>
```

But it threw the following exception:

> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>

If I log the results on my handler page like this:

```
System.out.println( "\n\nthere are " + results.getColumnCount() + " columns in the result set" );
for( int i=0; i<results.getColumnCount(); i++ )
{
    System.out.println( results.getHeading(i) + " --> " + results.getType(i) );
}
```

The logging seems to show fine on the server.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yeah give me a minute to run it again

Comment: The problem descriptions *"it's blowing up everytime I render the jsp"* and *"and the page broke :("* are **far** from helpful in understanding the concrete problem. Do not describe the problem from enduser's perspective, but from developer's perspective.

Comment: Just added error instack trace

Comment: Bad idea to name the variable the same thing you're iterating over--very confusing. In any case, if it's an instance of `DetResults` that's in `results`, of course you can't iterate over it--you'd need to iterate over one of its collections. And if it's using three parallel lists, it's doing it wrong.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in `<forEach>`

That will happen when the `<c:forEach items>` does not refer a valid object over which it can iterate. The object should be an `Object[]` (a plain array), a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html), [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html), [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Enumeration.html), [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) or [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) (see also [source code](https://github.com/jakartaee/tags/blob/master/api/src/main/java/jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagSupport.java#L628)). Anything else can't be iterated by `<c:forEach>`. Your `DetResults` class is not an instance of either of the aforementioned types, so it will fail.

Your `DetResults` class doesn't look right. It look basically like one God bean with a collection of all properties of multiple individual entities. This is not right. A bean class should represent at most one entity. Rewrite your `DetResults` class so that you basically end up with with a fullworthy collection of javabeans:

```java
List<DetResult> results = detDAO.fetchDetResults(paramBean);
```

so that you can access it as follows:

```xml
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
    ${result.heading}
    <c:forEach items="${result.data}" var="dataItem">
        ${dataItem}
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

*Note that I have fixed the `<c:forEach var>` attribute as well, it is not right to give it the same name as an existing object in the scope. It would only clash.*

If you really insist to keep your `DetResults` bean as it is, you could access it as follows:

```xml
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${results.columnCount}" varStatus="loop">
    ${results.headings[loop.index]}
    <c:forEach items="${results.data[loop.index]}" var="dataItem">
        ${dataItem}
    </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [Places where JavaBeans are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-javabeans-are-used)
- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc)

Comment: What If I cant rewrite so it's a list?...but use the lists within the bean?

Comment: Then just do so. Your `DetResults` class is however fishy. I think you should rather rewrite it to a `DetResult` class which has the properties `heading`, `type`, data`, etc and then have a `List<DetResult>`.

Comment: I updated the answer with some basic examples and useful "See also" links.

Comment: thanx alot...I really would have rather it been in a list but the guy that is building th back end says it has to be this way for now....thanx brother!

Comment: You're welcome. Much luck with this project and team. Sounds like painful.

Comment: Yeah it is painful...they have me doing so many different things...but it's cool...I gues when I become a "Principal" programmer" one day..I will look back on these days and laugh

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to iterate over the headings

```
<tr>
<c:foreach var="heading" items="${results.headings}">
  <th>${heading}</th>
</c:foreach>
</tr>
```

And then over the data...

```
<c:foreach var="row" items="${results.data}">
  <tr>
  <c:foreach var="i" items="${row}">
    <td>${i}</td>
  </c:foreach>
  </tr>
</c:foreach>
```

Or something along those lines?

Comment: Nad ...it didnt like that either :  `javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don&#039;t know how to iterate over supplied &quot;items&quot; in &lt;forEach&gt;
 at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:255)
 at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:219)`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think there probably is a way to get it working with the bean you have, but others are right when they say that redesigning the bean would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Check this below code in servlet class:

```
request.setAttribute("productList", products);
```

And the same should match in JSP page in `<c:forEach`:

```
<c:forEach var= "tempProducts" items= "${productList}">
```

NOTE: `"productList"` name should match exactly in 1 point 1 and 2
then it will.

It worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question... There is no such `productList` in there.