# Iterating through JSONArray in JSP using JSTL

Tags: java, json, spring, jstl, arrays

I am sending a list of custom objects with model, and a JSP as a view. My custom object has a property called `properties` and it is `JSONObject`. This property will have the value as

```
{"services":[{"name":"abcd"},{"name":"efgh"}]}
```

now I want to iterate through the JSONArray `[{"name":"abcd"},{"name":"efgh"}]`. Here is what I am doing to loop through

```
<c:if test="${not empty customObject.services}">
                 <c:forEach items="${customObject.services.getJSONArray(\"services\")}" var="Service" varStatus="rowCounterCh">
                     <li>${Service.name}</li>
                  </c:forEach>
 </c:if>
```

But this is  not able to iterate through the JSONArray. Am getting following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
```

So, what should I do to iterate through the JSONArray? Pls help

Comment: What concrete JSONArray implementation do you use?

Comment: @Taky sorry I couldn't understand that part:(

Comment: Exists a lot JSON library in Java. Wich do you use? What package is for joy JSONArray class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each tag should require a base interface for your items. JSONArray neither *java.util.Collection* nor *java.util.Iterable*. So For each tag implementation cannot iterate over the collection you pass into items attribute.

To solve this problem you may:

1. Generate HTML list view with JSP.
2. Or list item convert JSONArray into some appropriate Collection in *customObject.services.getJSONArray* method. JSONArray in gson implementation should has method: iterator, because it implements the Iterable interface. Try to return an [com.google.gson.JSONArray#iterator()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#iterator%28%29) instead of JSONArray in your #getJSONArray(String) method.

---

[more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134862/javax-servlet-servletexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jsptagexception-dont-know-ho)

Comment: I thought of getting the JSONarray and work upon that inside scriptlet, as `var itemStr ='<c:out value="${customObject.services.getJSONArray(\"services\")}"/>';` but this is giving me the json array as [{&#34;name&#34;:&#34;abcd&#34;},{&#34;name&#34;:&#34;efgh&#34;}] which is all the "s are replaced with &#034; how can I avoid this?

Comment: Try to set escapeXml attribute to false: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm

Answer (score 10):

I have something like this

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${jsonArray.length() -1}" var="index">
     ${jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("name")}
</c:forEach>
```

replace `${jsonArray.length() -1}` with your `jsonArray`. In this case, it is something like this

```
${customObject.services.getJSONArray(\"services\").length()}
```