# Can anyone please tell how to iterate and use a json array of maps in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, jstl

I have my json data (array of map) in my javascript and it's like as below:

```
[
{"HOURLY":"$309.75","Airport Fee":"$15.00","STC":"$52.66","Gratuity":"$61.95","Fuel Surcharge":"$5.00"},
{"HOURLY":"$309.75","Airport Fee":"$15.00","STC":"$52.66","Gratuity":"$61.95","Fuel Surcharge":"$5.00"}
]
```

I want to use the values of one of the maps in my jsp using some `object.value` or `map.getValueBykey` mechanism as if just like we use a model object passed from java to jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have an array of objects, treat it first like an array. So,

```
prices = [
  {"HOURLY":"$309.75","Airport Fee":"$15.00","STC":"$52.66","Gratuity":"$61.95","Fuel Surcharge":"$5.00"},
  {"HOURLY":"$329.75","Airport Fee":"$15.00","STC":"$52.66","Gratuity":"$61.95","Fuel Surcharge":"$5.00"}
];

console.log(prices[0].HOURLY); // will output "$309.75", value found in the first object
console.log(prices[1].HOURLY); // will output "$329.75", value found in the second object

// If you want to get all values of that one property in all objects in the array, you can iterate like this:
for(var i =0;i <prices.length;i++){
  console.log( prices[i].HOURLY);
}

// If you want to get all values for each property in a specific object, for example the first one in the array, you can iterate like this :
for(key in prices[0]){
  console.log("'" +key + "' = " + prices[0][key]);
}
```

This is how it's done in JavaScript.
I see you are asking about JSP however. Maybe an example like this is what you are looking for:
[javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134862/javax-servlet-servletexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jsptagexception-dont-know-ho)