# HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error]. An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/views/games.jsp] at line [24]

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

just following tutorial and got some problems with Spring MVC. Could you tell me why i got problems with my forEach loop and how i can repair it ?

> HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error]

---

Type Exception Report

> Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/views/games.jsp] at line [24]
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/views/games.jsp] at line [24]
>
> ```html
> 21: 
> 22:  <section class="container">
> 23:   <div class="row">
> 24:    <c:forEach items="${games}" var="game">
> 25:     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
> 26:      <div class="thumbnail">
> 27:      <img src="<c:url value="/resource/images/${game.gameId}.png"></c:url>" alt="image"  style = "width:100%"/>
> ```
>
> Stacktrace:
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:588)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1217)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> Root Cause
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:669)
>       org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.games_jsp._jspService(games_jsp.java:169)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1217)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> Root Cause
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>
>       org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:274)
>       org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:238)
>       org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
>       javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
>       org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.games_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(games_jsp.java:193)
>       org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.games_jsp._jspService(games_jsp.java:151)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1217)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

```html
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Gry</title>
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Gry</h1>
    <p>PS3  PS4  XBOX 360  XBOX ONE</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <c:forEach items="${games}" var="game">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
     <div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="<c:url value="/resource/images/${game.gameId}.png"></c:url>" alt="image"  style = "width:100%"/>
      <div class="caption">
       <h3>${game.gameName}</h3>
       <p>${game.gameDescription}</p>
       <p>${game.gamePrice} PLN</p>
       <p>Pozostało: ${game.gamesInStock}</p>
       <p>
        <a
         href=" <spring:url value="/games/game?id=${game.gameId}" /> "
         class="btn btn-primary"> <span
         class="glyphicon-info-sign glyphicon" /></span> Szczegóły
        </a>
       </p>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </c:forEach>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
 package com.kk.gamestore.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.MatrixVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.kk.gamestore.domain.Game;
import com.kk.gamestore.service.GameService;

@RequestMapping("/games")
@Controller
public class GameController {

 @Autowired
 private GameService gameService;

 @RequestMapping
 public String Welcome(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getAllGames());
  return "games";
 }

 @RequestMapping("/all")
 public String allGames(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getAllGames());
  return "games";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/{platform}")
 public String getGamesByPlatform(Model model, @PathVariable("platform") String gamePlatform) {
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getGamesByPlatform(gamePlatform));
  return "games";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/filter/{ByCriteria}")
 public String getGamesByFilter(@MatrixVariable(pathVar="ByCriteria")
 Map<String,List<String>> filterParams, Model model){
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getGamesByFilter(filterParams));
  return "games";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/game")
 public String getGamesById(@RequestParam("id") String gameId, Model model){
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getGameById(gameId));
  return "games";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getAddNewGameForm(Model model) {
 Game newGame = new Game();
 model.addAttribute("newGame", newGame);
 return "addGame";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processAddNewGameForm(@ModelAttribute("newGame") Game gameToBeAdded, BindingResult result) {
  String[] suppressedFields = result.getSuppressedFields();
  if (suppressedFields.length > 0) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Próba wiązania niedozwolonych pól: " + StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(suppressedFields));
  }
 gameService.addGame(gameToBeAdded);
 return "redirect:/games";
 }
 
 @InitBinder
 public void initialiseBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
 binder.setDisallowedFields("unitsInOrder", "discontinued");
 } 
}
```

Comment: `Root Cause javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach> ` can you provide your controller?

Comment: you might want to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134862/javax-servlet-servletexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jsptagexception-dont-know-ho

Comment: I checked this answer but not sure how to edit mine loop. I just added GameController.java in first post

Comment: what url do you call? `/game`?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/gamestore/games/game?id=G1
G1 is correctly id of one of game added in this application.

When i use other url for example:
http://localhost:8080/gamestore/games/game?id=b39jt 
(this id doesn't exist)i see page with message wrong GameId and i can go back to page with games, because i made class with this exception and that class work well. If you want i can show you other class, just tell me which one.

http://localhost:8080/gamestore/games work good. this page got all games, but when i want click button "details" and move to url from first sentence i got this error

Comment: Should i change RequestMapping for that to /gameId?

Comment: No, the problem is, that you can't use the same jsp for /games and /game. Your controller in /game only provide 1 single game Where it should provide a list, that is why your jsp-template breaks and you get an error

Comment: Thank you for answers and patience, now i understand all. I just want to say this is the best forum for programmers! And now if someone got similar errors there is a solution. I changed @RequestMapping(/game) like this.
@RequestMapping("/game")
 public String getGamesById(@RequestParam("id") String gameId, Model model){
  Game game = gameService.getGameById(gameId);
  model.addAttribute("game", game); 
  return "game";
 }
and in game.jsp i changed button back to "<spring:url value="/games" />"
cause i can't move back from page with details to page with all games.