# javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;

Tags: jsp

I DID try to follow the solution for the similar problem [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134862/javax-servlet-servletexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jsptagexception-dont-know-ho), but somehow I am still getting the error:

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>

I have object within an object. I don't know how to print being newbie.

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerVO {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "customer_seq", sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_SEQ", 
allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "customer_seq")
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;
@Column(name = "CUSTOMERID")
private long customerId;
@Column(name = "LOGINID")
private String loginId;
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP")
private Timestamp modTimestamp;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUST_PROFILE_ID")
private CustomerProfileVO customerProfileVO = new CustomerProfileVO();

public CustomerVO() {
}

public CustomerVO(int id, long customerId, String loginId, String password, 
Timestamp modTimestamp,
        CustomerProfileVO customerProfileVO) {
    this.id = id;
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.loginId = loginId;
    this.password = password;
    this.modTimestamp = modTimestamp;
    this.customerProfileVO = customerProfileVO;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getLoginId() {
    return loginId;
}

public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
    this.loginId = loginId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Timestamp getModTimestamp() {
    return modTimestamp;
}

public void setModTimestamp(Timestamp modTimestamp) {
    this.modTimestamp = modTimestamp;
}

public CustomerProfileVO getCustomerProfileVO() {
    return customerProfileVO;
}

public void setCustomerProfileVO(CustomerProfileVO customerProfileVO) {
    this.customerProfileVO = customerProfileVO;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CustomerVO [id=" + id + ", customerId=" + customerId + ", 
loginId=" + loginId + ", password=" + password
            + ", modTimestamp=" + modTimestamp + ", customerProfileVO=" + 
customerProfileVO + "]";
}

}
```

---

CustomerProfileVO.java

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_PROFILE")
public class CustomerProfileVO {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "customer_profile_seq", sequenceName = 
"CUSTOMER_PROFILE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = 
"customer_profile_seq")
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;
@Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LASTNAME")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "AGE")
private int age;
@Column(name = "GENDER")
private char gender;
@Column(name = "DOB")
private Date dob;
@Column(name = "DOORNO")
private int doorNo;
@Column(name = "STREETNAME")
private String streetName;
@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;
@Column(name = "STATE")
private String state;
@Column(name = "ZIPCODE")
private String zipcode;
@Column(name = "PROFILESTATUSCODE")
private String profileStatus;

public CustomerProfileVO() {

}

public CustomerProfileVO(int id, String firstName, String lastName, int age, char gender, Date dob, int doorNo,
        String streetName, String city, String state, String zipcode, String profileStatus) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.doorNo = doorNo;
    this.streetName = streetName;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
    this.profileStatus = profileStatus;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public int getDoorNo() {
    return doorNo;
}

public void setDoorNo(int doorNo) {
    this.doorNo = doorNo;
}

public String getStreetName() {
    return streetName;
}

public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
    this.streetName = streetName;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public String getProfileStatus() {
    return profileStatus;
}

public void setProfileStatus(String profileStatus) {
    this.profileStatus = profileStatus;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CustomerProfileVO [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", age=" + age
            + ", gender=" + gender + ", dob=" + dob + ", doorNo=" + doorNo + ", streetName=" + streetName
            + ", city=" + city + ", state=" + state + ", zipcode=" + zipcode + ", profileStatus=" + profileStatus
            + "]";
}
```

}

---

customerProfile.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  -->
<title>Login and Registration Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description"
content="Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3" />
<meta name="keywords"
content="html5, css3, form, switch, animation, :target, pseudo-class" />
<meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/animate-custom.css" 
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>
            User List</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div id="container_demo">

            <div id="wrapper">
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>LOGIN</th>
                                <th>PASSWORD</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="c" items="${customer}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${c.id}</td>
                                    <td>${c.loginId}</td>
                                    <td>${c.password}</td>
                                    <c:forEach var="x" 
items="${customer.customerProfileVO}">
                                        <td>${x.firstName}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>

                                    <td><a href="/edit-user-${c.id}"
                                        class="btn btn-success custom- 
width">edit</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/delete-user-${c.id}"
                                        class="btn btn-danger custom- 
width">delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the nested `c:forEach` you are in context of `c` variable and not `customer`, so change items reference to:

```
items="${c.customerProfileVO}">
```