# Show image as byte[] from database as graphic image in JSF page

Tags: image, jsf, arrays

I have image content as `byte[]` from database.

```
private byte[] image;
```

How can I show that byte array as a real graphic image in JSF page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not directly possible with `<h:graphicImage>`. It can only point to an URL, not to a `byte[]` nor `InputStream`. Basically, you need to make sure that those bytes are directly available as a HTTP response on the given URL, which you can then use in `<h:graphicImage>` (or even plain HTML `<img>`).

Provided that you're identifying the image by its ID like so:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/image/#{someBean.imageId}" />
```

Here's a kickoff example of such a servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/image/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private ImageService service;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Long id = Long.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1));
        Image image = service.find(id);
        response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(image.getName()));
        response.setContentLength(image.getBytes().length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(image.getBytes());
    }

}
```

A more advanced abstract template for a static resource servlet, supporting HTTP caching, can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29991447), along with a concrete example for serving from database.

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) on a JSF 2.2 + CDI environment, then you can instead use its [`<o:graphicImage>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) which can be used much more intuitively.

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{imageBean.getBytes(someBean.imageId)}" />
```

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageBean {

    @EJB
    private ImageService service;

    public byte[] getBytes(Long imageId) {
        return service.getImageBytes(imageId);
    }

}
```

Comment: i have only array of bytes from database nothing else, and i am using jsf so i have only managedBean, can you help me with that

Comment: Yes certainly. See above answer for kickoff examples of two possible ways. Just alter them if necessary to fit your situation.

Comment: @Balus May I ask what data type or from which package Image is in Image image = service.find(id); Is the Image image on that line a byte[], a Blob or something else?  Thanks

Comment: @p3ace: It's just your custom class. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1727603 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/30639785

Comment: @Balus Thank you. Still trying to absorb and understand every piece.

Comment: 2nd link ( <o:graphicImage> )  broken

Answer (score 5):

Just bind one String variable to image on UI.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, "#{imageString}">
```

For example you are loading the image byte[] from database then first encode it in base 64 String.

```
String imageString= new String(Base64.encodeBase64(byte array fetched from database));
```

Comment: although it might (does) work, page-caching wise this is not the best solution if you want to cache the page but refresh the image.

Comment: Hi all, this answer is correct but the img element is supposed to be written like this:
<img src="data:image/png;base64,#{imageString}">