# ImageService java

Tags: java, image

How can I declare such variable:

```
private ImageService service;
```

I saw it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606503/show-image-as-byte-from-database-as-graphic-image-in-jsf-page).

Do I have to add some kind of specific lib?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

Answer (score -1):

You should use `import` statement at the begining of your class.

```
import blablabla.ImageService;
```

where `blablabla` is a package.