# How to display buffered image in JSF without writing image on disk?

Tags: jsf, bufferedimage, uicomponents

I have a buffered image and I need to display it in a JSF page.
Is there any UI component available which can display a buffered image directly? I am using JSF 2.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show image as byte\[\] from database as graphic image in JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606503/show-image-as-byte-from-database-as-graphic-image-in-jsf-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have the buffered image, you could use the [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) library to which allows you to render images by passing a `byte[]` to the component

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{bean.image}" dataURI="true" />
```

If you have the buffered image you could convert to byte array like so:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write([image],[image_extension], baos);
byte[] imageToPassAsValueAttr = baos.toByteArray();
```

You could also create a [servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) to receive the image id as a get request and from that point on you can get the parameter value, find the resource and write the image content to response.

@BalusC has a nice example [here](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/04/imageservlet.html)