# How to print cn.replace("cn=", "") as <input value> using EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I am turnig my jsp code:

```
<%

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Entry var = (Entry) list.get(i);
        out.println(var.getCn().replace("cn=", ""));
        String cn = var.getCn();
        out.println("<form method=\"get\" action=\"Controller\">"
                + "<input type =\"hidden\" name=\"act1\" value = \"" + cn.replace("cn=", "") + "\">"
                + "<button type=\"submit\" name=\"act\"  value=\"SHOW\" id=\"act\" >Show</button>"
    }
```

into JSTL:

```
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
    <p>
        <c:out value="${item.getCn()} "></c:out>
        <p>
        <c:set var="item" value="${item.getCn()}"></c:set>
          <input type ="hidden" name="act1" value ="??????????????">
        <button type="submit" name="act"  value="SHOW" id="act">Show</button>
</c:forEach>
```

I don't know how to pass the parameter "value", easily uploadable through cn.replace("cn=", "") with jsp, to my servlet.

Answer (score 1):

First **remove** the below line:

```html
<c:set var="item" value="${item.getCn()}"></c:set>
```

It's overriding the `<c:forEach var="item">`.

As to the concrete question, you can just use singlequotes to represent a string in EL.

```html
<input ... value="${item.cn.replace('cn=', '')}">
```

Do note that on javabean properties you don't necessarily need to specify the whole method name as in `${item.getCn()}`. You can just use `${item.cn}`.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Places where JavaBeans are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-javabeans-are-used/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, also note that this is still prone to a [XSS attack hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application) if it concerns user-controlled input, but your original *scriptlet* approach was too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use the variable `item` the same way you used `cn` on your scriplet. Try something like this:

`value ="${item.replace('cn=', '')}"`

I'm not sure if you'll have problems with two variables named `item` in your JSP, you might want to change the name of one of them just in case. This would be the whole code:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
    <p>
        <c:out value="${item.getCn()} "></c:out>
        <p>
        <c:set var="cn" value="${item.getCn()}"></c:set>
          <input type ="hidden" name="act1" value ="${cn.replace('cn=', '')}">
        <button type="submit" name="act"  value="SHOW" id="act">Show</button>
```