# Java - Fields vs implemented Methods

Tags: java, memory, methods, field

I have to parse a JSON response and return objects which holds its data. But I am not sure which solution is more "memory-friendly":

**Method 1: Fields**

```
public class MyElement {

    private int var1;

    public MyElement(int var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

    public int getVar1() {
        return var1;
    }

}
```

**Method 1.1:** Direct access on field.
**Method 1.2:** Using builders/factories.

**Method 2:**

```
public interface MyElement {
    int getVar1();
}

// In Code
return new MyElement() {
    @Override
    public int getVar1() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't write such a thing: Use Jackson.  It requires that your objects follow the Java Bean standards.  Don't worry about memory friendly until you've profiled your app and data tells you there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: `public getVar1()` does not compile. Any difference between methods 1, 1.1 and 1.2 is negligible (though 1.1 is mutable unless you make your field `final`), but I would use method 1. This is because, with method 2, a new (anonymous) class is actually created. If this is executed many times, tons of classes are created. Of course, such differences usually wouldn't matter unless on a truly massive scale, so don't make memory an issue when it isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Java Bean Standard is a better approach as it followed in most of the implementations in software development.

I have good references links for you below which will explain details about your doubts :

[Places where JavaBeans are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-javabeans-are-used)

[When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)